# Closed form of infinite sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty{_{0}F_1}(;2;-kx)$ involving hypergeometric function 0F1

Tags: summation, closed-form, hypergeometric-function, zeta-functions, euler-maclaurin

Can we find a closed form for this infinite sum?

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty{_{0}F_1}(;2;-kx)$$

This arises from the problem of finding a closed form for

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{k-1}\frac{\zeta\left(2k\right)}{\left(2k\right)!}h^{2k-1}.$$

Here was my process. Begin with the special form of the Euler-Maclaurin formula.

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{h^{2k-1}B_{2k}}{(2k)!} \left(f^{(2k-1)}(b)-f^{(2k-1)}(a)\right)
&=\sum_{k=1}^n f(kh+a)-\left(\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{2}\right)
\\&-\frac{1}{h}\int_a^b f(t)dt
\\&-R
\end{align}
$$

where $h=\frac{b-a}{n}$. However, $h$ becomes unrestricted if we let $b\to\infty$ and $n\to\infty$.  We also may limit $a\to 0$ to simplify things.

Consider the Bessel Functions $J_n(x)$ and calculate via Taylor series

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{d^m}{dx^m}J_0\left(2\sqrt{x}\right)=\frac{(-1)^m}{m!}.$$

Then we have

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{d^{m-1}}{dx^{m-1}}\frac{J_1\left(2\sqrt{x}\right)}{\sqrt{x}}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{d^{m-1}}{dx^{m-1}}{_{0}F_1(;2;-x)}=\frac{(-1)^m}{m!}$$

and

$$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{d^m}{dx^m}{_{0}F_1(;2;-x)}=0.$$

Then since

$$\frac{(2\pi)^{2k}B_{2k}}{2(2k)!}=(-1)^{k-1}\zeta(2k),$$

the Euler-Maclaurin formula yields

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{k-1}\frac{\zeta\left(2k\right)}{\left(2k\right)!}h^{2k-1}
&=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{2h}+\pi\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{J_1\left(2\sqrt{2\pi hk}\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi hk}}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{2h}+\pi\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{_{0}F_1(;2;-2\pi hk)}
\end{align}.
$$

Comment: The original series is just the Maclaurin series for a trigonometric function.

Comment: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty{_0F_1}(;2;-kx)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nk^nx^n}{n!(n+1)!}$

Answer (score 1):

To make life simpler (at least mine), I prefer to use
$$\, _0F_1(;2;-k x)=\frac{J_1\left(2 \sqrt{k} \sqrt{x}\right)}{\sqrt{k} \sqrt{x}}$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty{_{0}F_1}(;2;-kx)=\frac 1{\sqrt{x}}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1{\sqrt{k}}J_1\left(2 \sqrt{k} \sqrt{x}\right)$$ By the integral test, the summation converges since
$$\int_1^\infty \frac 1{\sqrt{k}}J_1\left(2 \sqrt{k} \sqrt{x}\right)\,dk=\frac{J_0\left(2 \sqrt{x}\right)}{\sqrt{x}}$$

For the summation, I am stuck.

Comment: The summation over the 0th order J Bessel function is almost like a Schomilch Series for which there are special forms known. If not for the square rooted indices.